# aa.cls fails with `! LaTeX hooks Error` under tex live 2023

Tags: arxiv

The [EDP Sciences package](https://www.aanda.org/for-authors) for `aa.cls` fails under TL 2023 with:

```
! LaTeX hooks Error: Sorting rule for 'begindocument' hook applied too late.
(hooks)              Try setting this rule earlier.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.429 ...begindocument}{showkeys}{before}{nameref}

?
```

from a MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{aa}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

Is there a known workaround for such an error that can be applied to an arXiv submitter's tex file, or is there a straight-forward workaround that can be added to arXiv's copy of `aa.cls`?

Comment: load hyperref in the preamble: `\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}`

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do it. I'll add it to our canned response and knowledge base.

Comment: but the class should be adapted. It shouldn't load a package like hyperref in the begindocument hook. That is too late.

Comment: if the publisher applies a patch, we can update arXiv's tree with the new version.

Comment: well someone will have to tell to the publisher. Did you do it?

Comment: I have (within the last half hour), but have not yet received a reply.